# Object Not found in R code

Tags: r, surface, temperature

I'm trying to execute the next code, but in the last lines I found an error because the object 'HRdem' is not found (line 161):

```
library(maptools)
library(gstat)
library(rgdal)
library(lattice)

# Download MODIS LST images:
download.file("http://spatial-analyst.net/book/sites/default/files/LST2006HR.zip", destfile=paste(getwd(), "LST2006HR.zip", sep="/"))
unzip(zipfile="LST2006HR.zip", exdir=getwd())
unlink("LST2006HR.zip")
download.file("http://spatial-analyst.net/book/sites/default/files/HRtemp2006.zip", destfile=paste(getwd(), "HRtemp2006.zip", sep="/"))
unzip(zipfile="HRtemp2006.zip", exdir=getwd())

HRtemp2006 <- read.delim("HRtemp2006.txt")
str(HRtemp2006) # Mean daily temperature for 365 days (2006) at 123 locations;

HRtemp2006$cday <- floor(unclass(as.POSIXct(HRtemp2006$DATE))/86400)
floor(unclass(as.POSIXct("2006-01-30"))/86400)[[1]]

IDSTA <- readShapePoints("IDSTA.shp", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
IDSTA.utm <- spTransform(IDSTA, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84
 + datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
locs <- as.data.frame(IDSTA.utm)

names(locs) <- c("IDT_AK", "X", "Y")
str(locs)

dif.IDSTA <- merge(locs["IDT_AK"], data.frame(IDT_AK=levels(HRtemp2006$IDT_AK), sel=rep(1, length(levels(HRtemp2006$IDT_AK)))), by.x="IDT_AK", all.x=TRUE)

grids <- readGDAL("HRdem.asc")
names(grids@data)[1] <- "HRdem"
grids$HRdsea <- readGDAL("HRdsea.asc")$band1
proj4string(grids) <- IDSTA.utm@proj4string

grids.ll <- spTransform(grids[1], CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
grids$Lat <- grids.ll@coords[,2]
grids$Lon <- grids.ll@coords[,1]
str(grids@data)

LST.listday <- dir(pattern=glob2rx("LST2006_**_**.LST_Day_1km.tif"))
LST.listnight <- dir(pattern=glob2rx("LST2006_**_**.LST_Night_1km.tif"))
for(i in 1:length(LST.listday)){
LSTname <- strsplit(LST.listday[i], ".LST_")[[1]][1]
tmp1 <- readGDAL(LST.listday[i])$band1
tmp2 <- readGDAL(LST.listnight[i])$band1
# convert to celsius:
tmp1 <- ifelse(tmp1<=7500, NA, tmp1*0.02-273.15)
tmp2 <- ifelse(tmp2<=7500, NA, tmp2*0.02-273.15)
grids@data[,LSTname] <- (tmp1+tmp2)/2

}
summary(grids$LST2006_05_17)

IDSTA.ov <- over(grids, IDSTA.utm)
locs <- cbind(IDSTA.ov@data[c("HRdem", "HRdsea", "Lat", "Lon")], locs)
str(locs)

HRtemp2006locs <- merge(HRtemp2006, locs, by.x="IDT_AK")
str(HRtemp2006locs)

LSTdate <- rep(NA, length(LST.listday))
for(i in 1:length(LST.listday)){
LSTdate[i] <- gsub("_", "-", strsplit(strsplit(LST.listday[i], ".LST_")[[1]][1], "LST")[[1]][2])
}
# cumulative days since 2006-01-01:
LSTcdate <- round((unclass(as.POSIXct(LSTdate))-unclass(as.POSIXct("2006-01-01")))/86400, 0) 
LSTcdate <- c(LSTcdate, 365)
LSTdate[1:5]; LSTcdate[1:5]

MODIStemp <- expand.grid(IDT_AK=levels(HRtemp2006$IDT_AK), DATE=levels(HRtemp2006$DATE), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
MODIStemp$MODIS.LST <- rep(NA, length(MODIStemp[1]))
MODIStemp$MODIS.LST[1:(123*4)] <- rep(IDSTA.ov@data[!is.na(dif.IDSTA$sel), strsplit(LST.listday[i], ".LST_")[[1]][1]], 4)
for(i in 2:length(LST.listday)){
LSTname <- strsplit(LST.listday[i], ".LST_")[[1]][1]
d.days <- round((LSTcdate[i+1]-LSTcdate[i-1])/2, 0)
d.begin <- round((LSTcdate[i]-d.days/2)*123+1, 0)
d.end <- round((LSTcdate[i]+d.days/2)*123+1, 0)
MODIStemp$MODIS.LST[d.begin:d.end] <- rep(IDSTA.ov@data[!is.na(dif.IDSTA$sel),LSTname], d.days)
}
MODIStemp$MODIS.LST[(d.end+1):length(MODIStemp$MODIS.LST)] <- rep(IDSTA.ov@data[!is.na(dif.IDSTA$sel), strsplit(LST.listday[i], ".LST_")[[1]][1]], 2)

HRtemp2006locs$MODIS.LST <- MODIStemp$MODIS.LST[order(MODIStemp$IDT_AK)]
str(HRtemp2006locs)
tscale <- (((grids@bbox[1,"max"]-grids@bbox[1,"min"])+(grids@bbox[2,"max"]-grids@bbox[2,"min"]))/2)/(max(HRtemp2006locs$cday)-min(HRtemp2006locs$cday))
HRtemp2006locs$cdays <- tscale * HRtemp2006locs$cday
coordinates(HRtemp2006locs) <- c("X","Y","cdays")
proj4string(HRtemp2006locs) <- CRS(proj4string(grids))
HRtemp2006locs$c2days <- HRtemp2006locs@coords[,"cdays"]

MDTEMP.plt1 <- bubble(subset(HRtemp2006locs, HRtemp2006locs$cday==13150&!is.na(HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP), select="MDTEMP"), fill=F, col="black", maxsize=2, key.entries=c(0,10,20,30), main="13150")
MDTEMP.plt2 <- bubble(subset(HRtemp2006locs, HRtemp2006locs$cday==13200&!is.na(HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP), select="MDTEMP"), fill=F, col="black", maxsize=2, key.entries=c(0,10,20,30), main="13200")
MDTEMP.plt3 <- bubble(subset(HRtemp2006locs, HRtemp2006locs$cday==13250&!is.na(HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP), select="MDTEMP"), fill=F, col="black", maxsize=2, key.entries=c(0,10,20,30), main="13250")
MDTEMP.plt4 <- bubble(subset(HRtemp2006locs, HRtemp2006locs$cday==13300&!is.na(HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP), select="MDTEMP"), fill=F, col="black", maxsize=2, key.entries=c(0,10,20,30), main="13300")
print(MDTEMP.plt1, split=c(1,1,4,1), more=T)
print(MDTEMP.plt2, split=c(2,1,4,1), more=T)
print(MDTEMP.plt3, split=c(3,1,4,1), more=T)
print(MDTEMP.plt4, split=c(4,1,4,1), more=F)

GL001 <- subset(HRtemp2006locs@data, IDT_AK=="GL001", select=c("MDTEMP", "cday"))
KL003 <- subset(HRtemp2006locs@data, IDT_AK=="KL003", select=c("MDTEMP", "cday"))
KL094 <- subset(HRtemp2006locs@data, IDT_AK=="KL094", select=c("MDTEMP", "cday"))
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
scatter.smooth(GL001$cday, GL001$MDTEMP, xlab="Cumulative days", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", ylim=c(-12,28), main="GL001", col="grey")
scatter.smooth(KL003$cday, KL003$MDTEMP, xlab="Cumulative days", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", ylim=c(-12,28), main="KL003", col="grey")
scatter.smooth(KL094$cday, KL094$MDTEMP, xlab="Cumulative days", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", ylim=c(-12,28), main="KL094", col="grey")

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
scatter.smooth(HRtemp2006locs$HRdem, HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP, xlab="DEM (m)", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", col="grey")
scatter.smooth(HRtemp2006locs$HRdsea, HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP, xlab="Distance from the coast line (km)", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", col="grey")
scatter.smooth(HRtemp2006locs$MODIS.LST, HRtemp2006locs$MDTEMP, xlab="MODIS LST (\260C)", ylab="Mean daily temperature (\260C)", col="grey")

theta <- min(HRtemp2006locs$cday)
lm.HRtemp <- lm(MDTEMP~HRdem+HRdsea+Lat+Lon+cos((cday-theta)*pi/180)+MODIS.LST, data=HRtemp2006locs)
summary(lm.HRtemp)$adj.r.squared
hist(residuals(lm.HRtemp), col="grey", breaks=25)
plot(lm.HRtemp)
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your entire script on stackoverflow for someone to solve. Put some effort in isolating the problem in your code, and present the relevant chunk of code as a reproducible problem here. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?answertab=votes#tab-top) on how to post a good reproducible problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, the problem starts much earlier:

```
IDSTA.ov <- over(grids, IDSTA.utm)
locs <- cbind(IDSTA.ov@data[c("HRdem", "HRdsea", "Lat", "Lon")], locs)
```

In the first line, I believe the `x` and `y` values of the `over` statement are inverted, so it returns a null column.  Should be `over(IDSTA.utm, grids)`.  See `?over` in the `sp` package to validate which is which.

The second line fails because the IDSTA.ov object doesn't have an `@data` slot because it's not an S4 object.  It's just a plain `data.frame`. `over` only returns `data.frames` or `lists` You may need to recreate it as a `SpatialGridDataFrame` object, with the `data` slot that it creates along the way before you can use it in the manner you have in the rest of the program.  See `?"SpatialGridDataFrame-class"` for details.

As a result of these problems, the `locs` object is not created properly.  So, when you call the `lm` function later on, it fails at the first value, which happens to be `HRdem`.

Hope this helps.